# GAE Image providing and outgoing bandwidth

Tags: image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bandwidth

I am new to GAE and I have a hard time decreasing my outgoing bandwidth. I do think that most bandwidth is about IMAGE I'm hosting (e.x. Portraits or Background etc.)

It's there any difference between hosting a image in `data store (Blob)` or `< img src="\something.png >"` or `<img src="http://i.imgur.com/something.jpg"`(just about the outgoing bandwidth)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the imgur.com but both hosting from the project folder and the [blobstore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests) count towards the outgoing quota. [If you setup caching](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests) it should mitigate a lot of that.

> Outgoing Bandwidth (billable) The amount of data sent by the
>   application in response to requests.
>
> This includes:
>
> data served in response to both secure requests and non-secure
>   requests by application servers, static file servers, or the Blobstore